# RegEx for validating specific input

Tags: regex

The input accepts data in format: **%'letter' separator  %'letter' and so on.**

The separator can be: space, tab, colon or new line

Example:

```
%d %F %S   
or     
%d:%F:%S    
or    
%d:%F
%S
```

where the character after the '%' can be any letter

You cannot write something like:

```
%dddd %F %S
or 
%%d %F %S
```

So far I have done this:

```
^((%([a-zA-Z]){1})+\s?|:)+$
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
^((%[A-z])(\s|:))*(%[A-z])$
```

http://regexr.com?37626

Comment: This allows: %d%d  which is not valid

Comment: I've added the line begin and line termination, now it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this

```
(%[a-zA-Z][ \t\n;])*%[a-zA-Z]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But I'd suggest passing an case-insensitive flag to your matcher. Then the expression can be shortened to

```
(%[a-z][ \t\n;])*%[a-z]
```

Comment: This allows to have %d %d%d. Every pair of %'letter' should have a separator between them, except the last one